# Coordinates on image to clock time

Tags: python, math, geometry, angle

I have an image and a set of coordinates on that image (x and y) and I need to somehow turn them into a clock time. Here's an image showing what I'm trying to do:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwFat.jpg)

So point B will become 3 o'clock (it'll be rounded)
I have no idea where to start, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Geometrically you can define clock times based on radians and then round to the integers. As you have a vector between the two points you can calculate the angle and convert that to the correct clock value.

Comment: @AlbinSidås how would I do that? I'm not exactly the best at angles and math and stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# 坐标夹角转换为时间
# 计算两点间的夹角
import math


def calc_angle(other, center=(320, 240)):
    x = center[0] - other[0]
    y = center[1] - other[1]
    z = math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
    angle = round(math.asin(y / z) / math.pi * 180)
    return angle + 90


def angle_to_time(angle):
    second = angle * 120   # one angle = 120 seconds
    hour = second // 3600
    second %= 3600
    minute = second // 60
    second %= 60
    return hour, minute, second


print(angle_to_time(calc_angle((330, 240))))

(3, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Gives erroneous value for 6 or 9 o'clock.  Check this: `return (round(math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))) + 270) % 360`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to calculate the differences between the two points.

I would think of the problem as a graph where you have positive and negative X and Y axis with the center being 0,0 (you stationary point in the middle).

then you can for example:
if you have you top middle point A and you second moving point B.

```
A = (0, 0) B = (0, 1)
# if A[0] - B[0] < 0 then we know that we are on the left side of the clock and thus will need a value between 6 and 12
# if A[1] - B[1] < 0 then we know that its the horizontal plane and that we should be on the bottom side of the clock. 

# Then you can say that if the difference in X is 0 you know that the clock is 12 or 6.
```